# ClassCastException when using a custom displayer

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to use UIL with gridview layout in my project. For testing purposes I have modified the code from your project itself. My requirement is to display a TransitionDrawable with the original bitmap as the base image in layer zero and a tick mark in layer one. Here is custom BitmapDisplayer code.

```
public class customBitmapDisplayer implements BitmapDisplayer
{

public static Drawable tick;
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
TransitionDrawable mytransition;

@Override
public Bitmap display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView)
{
BitmapDrawable base_image = new BitmapDrawable(imageView.getResources(), bitmap);
layers[0] = base_image;
layers[1] = tick;

mytransition = new TransitionDrawable(layers);
imageView.setImageDrawable(mytransition);
return bitmap;
}

public customBitmapDisplayer(Drawable tick_mark)
{
tick = tick_mark;
}
}
```

I have also modified getView slightly. Here is the code.

```
if(selected[position])  //selected is a boolean array
{
TransitionDrawable quickTransition = (TransitionDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
quickTransition.startTransition(0);
}
```

By the way I'm using UIL 1.8.0, default ImageConfiguration, DisplayImageOptions modified to use with a custom BitmapDisplayer, whose code is above. I tested on android 2.3.4 and found no problem but on android 4.0.4, **I got a ClassCastException in getView method saying that BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to TransitionDrawable when I scrolled through the whole gridview after 'selecting' every image.**

Here is the stacktrace.

```
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(ImageGridActivity.java:219)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2019)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1338)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:343)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.widget.GridView.fillUp(GridView.java:384)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:260)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4567)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:3834)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-20 20:46:40.797: E/AndroidRuntime(11943):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 20:46:44.377: I/Process(11943): Sending signal. PID: 11943 SIG: 9
```

ImageGridActivity.java has the following code in line 219.

```
TransitionDrawable quickTransition = (TransitionDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
```

Here is my getView code.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);

    if(selected[position])
    {

        TransitionDrawable quickTransition = (TransitionDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
        quickTransition.startTransition(0);

    }
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code in android emulator running 4.1. Problem persists. Somebody please help me.

Comment: Stacktrace from LogCat?

Comment: Please makes edits to your post rather than posting answers with updates.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will make sure not to repeat again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your `getView()` method to following:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                if(selected[position]) {
                    TransitionDrawable quickTransition = (TransitionDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
                    quickTransition.startTransition(0);
                }
            }
        });
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nostra, should I change my BitmapDisplayer too?

Comment: No. I think it's not needed.